# Check if paramiko SCP connection is still active

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, paramiko, scp

I'm writing a Python3 timelapse script for my RaspberryPi that is supposed to take a photo every hour and then upload it to my server using SCP.

So far I am getting the Pi to take a snapshot every hour and things seem to be working. However, when I make my SCP connection I get the error

> File "/home/pi/timelapse.py", line 62, in upload_photo
>       scp.close()
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'scp' referenced before assignment

This makes no sense to me as the scp.close() function is only called inside the try-block, after the SCP-variable has been initialized only lines before. In other words, if an exception is to occur before that line, I would have entered the except-block already, and I am not supposed to come to this line. As I see things, the variable 'SCP' HAS to be defined whenever I come to this line, but I suspect that might not be the case...

The code that I use to upload the photo is as follows:

```
def upload_photo(filename):
    try:
            uploaded = False
            ssh = SSHClient()
            ssh.load_system_host_keys()
            ssh.connect('my.server', username="myUsername" password="myPass")

            scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())

            scp.put(filename, remote_path="~/snaps")
            uploaded = True
            scp.close()
            ssh.close()
    except Exception as err:
            send_error_mail(err, filename)
    finally:
            if uploaded:
                    os.system("rm " + filename)
            else:
                    os.system("mv " + filename + " picturecache")
```

If anyone has come across this error before and know how to resolve it, I would very much appreciate an answer to my question! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree that your error is impossible from this code—but that means that what’s actually running (on the Pi!) is something else.  Double-check that you’ve installed/updated it correctly…

Comment: Okay so I'm getting closer here. Now I reallize that my code actually yields
Error: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
What can cause this?

Comment: You’d need to start by editing your question to give a lot more detail and context.